# RDLC Report not displayed

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

I done my button and report viewer in a single form. But, My report is not shown as well as no data.

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionstring = "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Data Source=ECSTSRD;Initial Catalog=SSWSQL;User ID=sswuser;Password=sswuser123";
    SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

    myconnection.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT customer, imp_license_no, psq_level FROM customer WHERE customer= @cust1";

    SqlCommand custcom = new SqlCommand(sql, myconnection);

    custcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust1", cboFrom.SelectedValue.ToString());

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(custcom);
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    da.Fill(ds, "customer");

    cboFrom.DataSource = ds.Tables["customer"];
    cboFrom.DisplayMember = "customer";
    cboFrom.ValueMember = "customer";

    myconnection.Close();

    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();

    reportViewer1.Reset();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customerBindingSource));
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a quick glance i suspect that it will be somehting to do with this

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customerBindingSource));
```

I don't see `customerBindingSource` anywhere in your code.  It probably should reference the datatable `ds.Tables["customer"]`.

Comment: Error shownafter I change to ds.: The report data source object must be of the type System.Data.DataTable, System.Collections.IEnumerable, System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource, or System.Type.

Do u have any idea on this?

Comment: sorry, I forgot about the datatables.  ok, try ds.Tables["customer"] as it was the customer table that you filled with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    1-reportViewer1.Reset();
    2-reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    3-reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
    4-reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customerBindingSource));
    5-reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    6- reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

and you shoud be sure about the design in rdlc file is like the data set design

Comment: Please highlight **what** you've changed and **why** you've done so in your answer.